# Compare two lists & only keep rows with matching values

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a list of asin numbers and a dataframe which has the column of asin numbers. So I want to compare the list with the asin number in the dataframe & just keep the rows which have matching asin numbers from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.isin()`:

```
df = df[df.asin.isin(asin_list)]
```

or

```
df = df.query("asin.isin(@asin_list)")
```